# Why would CRM_Utils_Hook::entityTypes($entityTypes) return results with a non-civicrm table?

Tags: core

I've traced a crash in dedupe to a NULL entity. I've worked around that, but I should figure out why the entity is NULL. I've gotten as far as CRM_Utils_Hook::entityTypes($entityTypes)

it's return value seems to refer to a TEAM table that doesn't exist in CiviCRM. I may have created such a table in the same DB months ago, but I don't think it ever followed a naming convention that would have 'fooled' CiviCRM into categorizing it as a core table.

I plan to keep digging, but now seems like a good time to ask for advice. Anyone seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have extension or module that implements entityTypes() hook. Try grepping TEAM inside your module or extension directory, if found either remove the code if its implemented in entityType hook or disable the extension or module if not in use

Comment: Thanks! That was it! I carelessly used civicrm_team as the table name.